# Package for reporting GUI problem in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, 19.10

I have the following GUI annoyance:

Sometimes when opening a new application window the window opens to as the topmost window and it is possible to work. This is the expected behavior.

Other times the window opens but is is hidden under all other windows on my desktop and I need to look for it. This is wrong.
There is a new message (toast) that appears sometimes saying something like "your window is ready" and if I am fast enough and click it then the new window becomes topmost and active.

Expected behavior:
if I open a window/application I would like it to open as fast as possible and be the topmost active application.
I do not want to mess with toasts or searching windows - this is an annoyance.

So, my question is: how to report this?
What is the correct package?
Where is the correct place to report?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug it's a feature. Follow the steps from this answer:

- [Gnome Shell - How to prevent an application from starting behind the application in focus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192009/gnome-shell-how-to-prevent-an-application-from-starting-behind-the-application#comment1994865_1192009)

> Gnome Shell, which is used by Ubuntu, has the feature that launched
>   applications are opened in the background. While this may be desirable
>   in some workflows, many users will consider this an annoyance. A gnome
>   Shell extension, appropriately named "No Annoyance", changes this
>   behavior, and makes sure a launched application is immediately raised.
>
> Install the extension with the command `sudo apt install
>   gnome-shell-extension-no-annoyance`, or using Synaptic Manager (not
>   installed by default) or even using "Software". To enable the
>   extension after installation, you can use "Gnome Tweaks" (not
>   installed by default).

Comment: Thanks for the very elaborate anwser.

gnome-shell-extension-no-annoyance 
I bet Steve Jobs is rolling in laughter

Why not releasing a proper UI and if anyone is really really interested they can run "gnome-shell-extension-with-annoyance" or "gnome-shell-extension-medium-annoyance"

Comment: I'm sorry to deceive you it is not my *"elaborate answer"* and I **cannot** take credit. Please click on the link and vote for the original author.

Comment: This is definitely a bug. Maybe not in the code but in the overall result.
I wonder how to make them fix it is they do nor recognize it is a problem..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a bug report related to the problem.

It is under the topic "gnome-shell package"

Looks like there is an active discussion and even ability to vote.

This is the link for this problem:

```
[https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1825710][1]
```

Similar problems should probably be reported in the same site and same reporting system.